# how to implement an atomic assignment on AIX/powerpc?

Tags: kernel, aix, powerpc, atomic

I'm porting a kernel extentsion to 32/64 bit AIX on multi-processor PowerPC, written in C. I don't need more than atomic read operation and atomic write operations (I have no use for fetch-and-add, compare-and-swap etc.)
Just to clarify: to me, "atomicity" means not only "no interleaving", but also "visibility across multiple cores".
The operations operate on pointers, so operations on 'int' variables are useless to me.

If I declare the variable "volatile", the C standard says the variable can be modified by unknown factors and is therefore not subject to optimizations.

From what I read, it seems that regular reads and writes are supposed to be non-interleaved, and the [linux kernel souces](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-powerpc/atomic.h?v=2.6.25;a=powerpc) seem to agree. it says:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("stw%U0%X0 %1,%0" : "=m"(v->counter) : "r"(i));
```

`stw` is "store word", which is supposedly atomic, but I don't know what the "%U0%X0" means. I do not understand how this assembly instruction imposes visibility.
When I compile my kernel extension, 'std' is used for the assignment I want, but it should also be atomic for a 64 bit machine, from what I read. I have very little understanding of the specifics of PowerPC and its instruction set, However I did not find in the assembly listing of the compiled file any memory barrier instructions ("sync" or "eieio").

The kernel provides the fetch_and_addlp() service which can be used to implement atomic read (`v = fetch_and_addlp(&x, 0)`, for example).

So my questions are:

1. is it enough to declare the variable 'volatile' to achieve read and write atomicity in the sense of visibility and no-interleaving?
2. if the answer to 1 is "no", how is such atomicity achieved?
3. what is the meaning of "%U0%X0" in the Linux PowerPC atomic implementation?

Comment: That is not the meaning of "atomic"! If you want ordering guarantees, use a memory barrier. (Or just use a lock, because apparently everyone gets barriers wrong.)

Comment: @tc: Unfortunately, the microprocessor community does not agree on the meaning of the word "atomic".   When I defined the Intel x86 memory ordering architecture circa 1991, I used the definition tc uses - "atomic" referring to seeing an operation all done or not done at all, never half way down, and "memory ordering" as a different thing.  ARM, however, more recently uses "atomic" to refer to memory ordering, "single location atomicity" to what tc and I called just "atomic", and "multi-location-atomicity" or "write atomicity" to refer to memory ordering properties of the system.

Answer (score 1):

There are idiosyncrasies in the GCC inline assembly syntax.

in the line,

```
__asm__ __volatile__("stw%U0%X0 %1,%0" : "=m"(v->counter) : "r"(i));
```

the `m` is an output operand and the `r` is an input operand.  The %1 and %0 refer to the argument order (0->m, 1->r)

the `stw` assembly instruction takes 2 arguments and the %U0%X0 are constraints on the arguments.   These constraints are to force GCC to analyze the arguments and make sure you dont do something stupid.  As it turns out, `U' is powerpc-specific (I'm used to the X64 constraint set :).  The full list of constraints can be found in :

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to answer questions 1 and 2, but not 3:

1. No, its not enough.
2. Memory barriers are still required. I used the XLC built in __lwsync(). This should both prevents reordering by the processor and publishes the change to other processors.